# Ajax Extension Works With Master Page But Not With Content Page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have Installed Ajax Extension and added reference to the application. I am facing very strange problem that my master page accept the Ajax Extension Tools where as my content page throw error like “Element ScriptManager/UpdatePanel is not a known Element."

```
My WebConfig:
<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration>

  <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off">

  </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>

  </system.web>
  </configuration>


My contentPage:
<%@ Page Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/yuva.master" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeBehind="PicSave.aspx.cs" Inherits="YuvaRK12.PicSave" %>


 <asp:Content ID="MypicSave" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID= "MainCPH" >
 <table id="Main" style="width:100%; height:350px; background-color:White;"><tr><td>

 <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="vis" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

   <table id="Photo" style=" margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
   <tr><td>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />

   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>

       <input  id="ImageBT"  
               type="button" 
               value="Upload Image" 
               runat="server" 
               onserverclick="ImageBT_ServerClick" style=" float:left;" />

   </td></tr><tr><td style="border-style:ridge;  border-width:3px;">
   <center>

         <asp:Image id="MyImg" runat="server" 
                    style="width:150px; 
                    height:150px;"  
                    BorderStyle="solid" 
                    BorderWidth="1px"/>
   </center>
   </td></tr></table>  <!-- Photo End Here-->

    <center>
    <table><tr><td>
     <asp:Button ID="SBtn" runat="server" 
                 Text="Submit" BorderStyle="ridge"  
                 BorderWidth="4px" 
                 OnClick="SBtn_Click" />
   </td></tr></table>
   </center>

   </td></tr></table><!--Main End here-->
   </asp:Content>
```

What I am missing here?. Very strange Ajax Extension is working with master page but not with content page!. What is the solution of it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have utilized the golden two weeks for such puzzle and at last succeed. I have search many articles most of the article suggests as above which creates misunderstanding for newbie like me.

The solution is:

```
<pages>
<controls>
  <add tagPrefix="ajax" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions,   Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</controls>
```

The alteration of "asp" to "ajax" in the section pages/controls of web.config configuration would lead you to full controls over ajax extension in existing Asp.Net Web Application.

Answer (score 2):

YES. You can use AJAX in your Web App without installing **ajax toolkit**.

To use AJAX in your Web app, there's pre-defined library that you can use. You can find these controls under "AJAX Extensions" in toolbox. Use **Script Manager** and **Update Panels** to  make partial postback to server.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

In above code onclick of *Button1* only *Label1* would be passed to the server and not *Label2*. Any controls outside the update panel would not go to server and hence it's a partial postback.

You can explore more about **Triggers** as well to make AJAX callbacks more efficient.

**Note:** AJAX toolkit is for advance controls, like accordion, animations etc. You don't need them for simple AJAX based web application.

Comment: hnDabhi, The toolbox shows the Ajax extension but when I drag and drop it to the page it seems like unable control shows that no property are display for the concern control like script manager and update panel and error underline shows there.

Comment: Can you share some of your code, error or screenshots; anything? So that it broads up the problem to me.

Comment: note:- It is on Asp.net Web Application not Ajax enable Application

Comment: It doesn't need to be AJAX enabled Application. Simple Asp.net Web Application should work. 

I didn't understand when you say **no property available in my application**. The only property we need to set in script manager are **id** and **runat**. Is your code throwing any error at runtime? If so, share them. Make sure your script manager is placed inside a _form_ tag with `runat="server"` property. Ideally this should be in your _Master Page_ as you have one.

Comment: It is not compulsory to add it on master page. If suppose only few not all content page require it than you may add ScriptManager on Content Page. I think the problem is how to deal it with master page and content page and exact where it has to be place on content page. what you think about that?.

Comment: It is not necessary to place it on master page. It can be in content page. You have to place it before any control that uses script manager and as i mentioned earlier, it has to be in a form tag. But ideally put it on master page, and use _script manager proxy_ on content pages.

Comment: Which is your targetFramework,  I mean the .Net version you are using? The problem might be with your web.config. Try adding this in your web.config. `<system.web>

<pages>
<controls>

<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</controls>

</pages>
</system.web>`. Go through this [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1054146/1495802.aspx). It might help.

Comment: The master page problem solved it allowed to declare scriptmanager but content page not allow to declare either script manager proxy or UpdatePanel it shows the error "like Element scriptmanagerproxy is not a known element" same error in UpdatePanel declaration.

Comment: It is not allow to declare than I am trying to drag and drop type but it's throw error "Element scripmanagerproxy/updatpanel is not a known element"

Comment: Download [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883), install it and restart your VS. You shall see **AJAX Extentions** tab in toolbox and it should work fine.

Comment: have a look at my answer